# How to capitalize the first letter after dash in PHP?

Tags: php

```
$q = 'durham-region';

$q = ucfirst($q);

$q = 'Durham-region';
```

How would I capitalize the letter after the dash (Durham-Region)?  Would I have to split the two and capitalize?

Comment: `mb_convert_case()` https://3v4l.org/YOWZs

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Updated Solution**

As of PHP 5.5, the `e` modifier for `preg_replace` has been deprecated. The best option now is to use one of the more modern suggestions that does not use this, such as:

```
$q = ucwords($q, '-);
```

or

```
$q = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $q)));
```

**Original Answer**

You could use `preg_replace` using the `e` modifier this way:

```
$test = "durham-region";
$test = preg_replace("/(\w+)/e","ucfirst('\\1')", $test);
echo $test;
// Durham-Region
```

Comment: Note: Using preg_replace_callback can lead to a white screen as in my case (unexpected T_FUNCTION). Thanks @Kelly for providing the other options!

Comment: Watch out, using the preg_replace with a word that contains Umlaute, e.g. `$test = "wärme-test";` leads to results like "WäRme-Test". In other words, the letter after the Umlaut also gets capitalized.

Comment: Note, This does not only capitalize after a dash, but after EVERY non-word-character, even the first character of the string is capitalized.

Comment: `create_function` is also deprecated in PHP 7.4

Comment: preg_replace is a poor solution and unsuitable from a high-scale point of view.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to the `delimiter` parameter of [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php), since PHP 5.4.32 and 5.5.16, it is as simple as this:

```
$string = ucwords($string, "-");
```

Comment: That also do the Job: <php>$string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8');</php>

Answer (score 9):

A one-liner that doesn't envolve using the `e` PCRE modifier:

```
$str = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $str)));
```

Comment: This one-liner worked for me (also works for words that contain Umlaute).

Answer (score 1):

another oneliner:

```
str_replace(' ','',ucwords(str_replace('-',' ',$action)))
```

Comment: just a caution, this could affect strings that both contain a space and a dash, but for single words, this is also good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `ucfirst()` simply capitalized the first letter of the string. If you want multiple letters capitalized, you must create multiple strings.

```
$strings = explode("-", $string);
$newString = "";
foreach($strings as $string){
    $newString += ucfirst($string);
}

function ucfirst_all($delimiter, $string){
    $strings = explode("-", $string);
    $newString = "";
    foreach($strings as $string){
        $newString += ucfirst($string);
    }
    return $newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a regular expression callback method like this:

```
$q = preg_replace_callback('/\-([a-z]+)/g', create_function(
            '$m', 'return "-" . ucfirst($m[1]);'
        ),$q)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that the solutions provided here will not work with UTF-8 strings!

```
$str = "Τάχιστη αλώπηξ βαφής ψημένη γη, δρασκελίζει-υπέρ νωθρού κυνός";
$str = explode('-', mb_convert_case( $str, MB_CASE_TITLE ) );
$str = implode('-', array_map('mb_convert_case', $str, array(MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8")) );
echo $str;

// str= Τάχιστη Αλώπηξ Βαφήσ Ψημένη Γη, Δρασκελίζει-Υπέρ Νωθρού Κυνόσ
```

Comment: I get `mb_convert_case() expects parameter 2 to be int, string given` on your third line

Answer (score 0):

look

```
function UpperCaseAfterDash($wyraz)
  {
     $rozbij = explode('-',$wyraz);
     echo $rozbij[0].'-'.
     ucfirst($rozbij[1]);
  }

UpperCaseAfterDash("input-text");
```

Above function returns **input-Text**

If you need only uppercase letter after one dash for example with city names (Jastrzębie-Zdrój) it will be enough, but if you need more than one... , just count how many array elements (after explode in above code) exists, then use loop.

Greets,

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalized function that lets you capitalize after any character or string of characters. In the specific case the questioner asked about, the needle is the dash.

```
function capitalizeAfter( $needle, $haystack ) {

  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "a", $needle . "A", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "b", $needle . "B", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "c", $needle . "C", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "d", $needle . "D", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "e", $needle . "E", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "f", $needle . "F", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "g", $needle . "G", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "h", $needle . "H", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "i", $needle . "I", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "j", $needle . "J", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "k", $needle . "K", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "l", $needle . "L", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "m", $needle . "M", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "n", $needle . "N", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "o", $needle . "O", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "p", $needle . "P", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "q", $needle . "Q", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "r", $needle . "R", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "s", $needle . "S", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "t", $needle . "T", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "u", $needle . "U", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "v", $needle . "V", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "w", $needle . "W", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "x", $needle . "X", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "y", $needle . "Y", $haystack );
  $haystack = str_replace( $needle . "z", $needle . "Z", $haystack );

  return $haystack;

}
```